# Binding html data from quill editor is not displaying as expected in Angular 2^

Tags: css, angular, ngx-quill

I am trying to integrate quill editor in Angular application. Here I am using `ngx-quill` npm module.
My issue is when I am using `Blockquote`, `Code block`, those are not displaying as expected when I am binding it using `innerHtml`

Please have a look into the below attachment.

[image]

here are the styles that are added in the `angular.json`

```
 "styles": [
          "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
          "src/styles.scss",
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
          "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
          "./node_modules/quill-emoji/dist/quill-emoji.css",
          "./node_modules/quill-mention/dist/quill.mention.min.css"
        ],
```

Can someone help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it actually creating the proper HTML output you want?  If it is, then it's possible you don't have the CSS styles you want. From the image, the code block looks like a monospaced font on the bottom, so thats probably what is happening.

Comment: Okay, but what I am supposed  to do, for getting output as like what is there inside the editor ?

Comment: I edited with styles which I added in  angular.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make your own CSS classes to style the output. Quill's CSS styles are scoped to the editor. If you want all code blocks to be styled that way, or just particular ones styled that way based on a class name, it's up to you.

If you right click on the code in the editor and inspect element, chrome will show you the CSS styles applied to that object in the editor.

[image: chrome inspector example]

For the code / pre example its this:

```css
.ql-snow .ql-editor pre.ql-syntax {
    background-color: #23241f;
    color: #f8f8f2;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

If you want to re-use all of the Quill Styles, you can wrap your div that you are setting the innerHtml on, like this.  I can't guarantee that quill will output the same exact classes for the HTML output, but for the case of `pre.ql-syntax` it seems like it does.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill-example-mkuhbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```html
  <div class="ql-snow">
    <div class="ql-editor" [innerHtml]="htmlText"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the styles are not applying for innrHtml

Comment: please add an example stack blitz, without seeing the fully outputted HTML to debug the CSS I can't really help much more.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill-example-mp7ucc

Comment: @VenkateshVoona I've updated the example with a fork of your stackblitz

Comment: The styles are not working for the specific classes @cjd82187

Comment: Not sure what you mean there.  But if you are just trying to copy quill's css, it will not work.  The markup inside the editor will have overly specific CSS classes (the theme you are using, the editor, then the "pre.ql-syntax" class), but the final HTML Output will not.  The CSS selectors will not match and you will need to create your own.  I only included the "pre" tag as an example.

Comment: Yes, you added pre tag, but if we write like that, where ever the pre tag is there, the css will apply. I am trying to apply the css for ".ql-snow .ql-editor pre.ql-syntax"

Comment: I've updated the example stack blitz and code here, you can add the ql-* classes to the html to match the css selectors

Comment: Thank you @cjd82187 , its working but still we can't use the pre tag for other pages. As the html is dynamically generating we can use the ":host::ng-deep .ql-syntax" like this. Now its working fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-quill-example-xhohbt

Comment: I've updated my answer and stack blitz, I removed the very generic pre code.  Your ":host::ng-deep .ql-syntax" should work for that particular component. If you wrap the inner html like I do, any of the other quill specific styles should work too

Answer (score 3):

**For the feature Uses**

I also Had a this issue and `cjd82187` answer is not work for html code like below,

```
<ul><li><strong>This slipcase includes the following books:</strong></li><li class=\"ql-indent-1\"><span style=\"color: rgb(230, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(235, 214, 255);\">Winnie the Pooh and some Bees</span></li><li class=\"ql-indent-1\"><span style=\"color: rgb(230, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(235, 214, 255);\">Pooh Goes Visiting and Pooh and Piglet nearly catch a Woozle</span></li><li><strong>Author:</strong> A.A Milne</li><li><strong>Reading Age:</strong> <span style=\"color: rgb(230, 0, 0);\">3+ years</span></li></ul>
```

This contains an inline style class those are not working with `innerHtml`. For that, you can use `HTML transform`. This is the way I used to resolve this issue.

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

transformHtml(htmlTextWithStyle): SafeHtml {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlTextWithStyle);
}

<div class="ql-snow">
  <p class="ql-editor" [innerHtml]="transformHtml(yourHtmlText)"></p>
</div>
```